# how to simplify $S_k=S_0 \cdot e^{\frac{W_k+k}{2} \cdot ln(u)+(k-\frac{W_k+k}{2})ln(d)}$

Tags: calculus

I'm learning how to derive a formula and I do not quite see how to simplify from step one to step two?

step one: $$S_k=S_0 \cdot e^{\frac{W_k+k}{2} \cdot ln(u)+(k-\frac{W_k+k}{2})ln(d)}$$

step two: $$S_k=S_0 \cdot e^{W_k \cdot \frac{ln(u)-ln(d)}{2}+k \cdot \frac{ln(u)+ln(d)}{2}}$$

I tried to distribute the $ln(u)$ and $ln(d)$ but that did not look like I was getting closer.

Comment: All you have to show is $\frac{W_k+k}{2}\ln u+(k-\frac{W_k+k}{2})\ln d=W_k\frac{\ln u-\ln d}{2}+k\frac{\ln u+\ln d}{2}$ which is obvious.

Comment: I know that's what I have to show, for some reason I don't know why that is obvious, meaning what property or simplification leads to that?

Comment: Every term on the left has either a $W_k$ factor or a $k$ factor. Look at the $W_k$ ones first. there are two of them. Compare to the rhs. Similarly for the three terms involving $k$.

Comment: thank you, I see what I had to do.